# Game of zeros and ones (Google interview)

Tags: algorithm, math

I was asked this question a while ago at my Google interview and so far I had no luck finding a good answer to it:
This is a 2-player game where you are given a string of zeros and ones. At each turn a player can choose a 1 (or as many 1s next to each other) and change it/them to 0/0s. The player who changes the last 1 (or group of 1s) to 0/0s is the winner of the game.

For example starting with 0101110. The first player has 7 possible moves:

1. 0**1**01110 -> 0**0**01110 (Second player can win)
2. 010**1**110 -> 010**0**110 (Second player can win)
3. 0101**1**10 -> 0101**0**10 (Second player can win)
4. 01011**1**0 -> 01011**0**0 (Second player can win)
5. 010**11**10 -> 010**00**10 (First player can win)
6. 0101**11**0 -> 0101**00**0 (First player can win)
7. 010**111**0 -> 010**000**0 (Second player can win)

The goal is to figure out if there is a winning strategy if you start first.
We assume here that both players are good players (meaning that they wont make mistakes!)

**Update:**
This game is slightly different than Nim (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), for Nim the number of piles (or heaps) remain the same at every turn whereas here at every turn you may change the number of piles.
For instance if we do 0101**1**10 -> 0101**0**10 initially we have two piles of size 1 and 3 but after the move we will have 3 piles of size 1.

Comment: a reasonable player will only make two decisions, take all consecutive ones, or take all ones but one.

Comment: What if you start with `101`? The player who moves first loses in this case, since they are forced to change one of the `1`s, so the second player can win on their turn.

Comment: @arshajii yes thats true and in that case there is no winning strategy. "The goal is to figure out **if there is a winning strategy** if you start first"

Comment: Did you sign NDA form?

Comment: It is a nim game, think like this way: group of consecutive 1 is a pile of stones, and different groups means different pile, and there is 2 players...

Comment: @PhamTrung it was a phone interview and I did not sign anything for it

Comment: Are you seeking a program that, given a string will give you an answer, or are you seeking a simple rule that can be applied in your head to strings to give you the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `nim[n]` be the nimber of a sequence of `n` ones. We then have the following recurrence relation:

`nim[n] = mex{nim[i] xor nim[j]: i, j >= 0, i + j < n}`

(See [Sprague-Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) for the general theory.)

From this recurrence relation, you can try to calculate the first several terms of the sequence `nim`, and you will find that it seems `nim[n] = n`.

Then a proof can be deduced easily, which I shall leave to you.

---

Thus a sequence of `n` consecutive ones is actually equivalent to a Nim pile of size `n`. Now it is easy to find the result of any game.

For example, if we have `0101110`, then it is equivalent to two piles of Nim, of size `1` and `3` respectively. Hence the total nimber is equal to `1 xor 3 = 2`, which is non-zero, so the first player wins.

As another example, if we have `1110011111000111111`, then the total nimber is equal to `3 xor 5 xor 6 = 0`, so the first player loses.

---

EDIT: As to your question about the change of piles, here are some more explanations.

Although the number of piles will change, the key point is the following:

- if a status has zero nimber, any valid move must change it to a non-zero nimber status.
- if a status has non-zero nimber, then there must exists a valid move, which changes it to a zero nimber status.

Thus for the winner, the strategy is to leave a zero nimber status to his opponent.

Example: let us begin with the sequence `1110011111000111111`, which I denote by `3, 5, 6` for short.

If the first player replace the `6` by the sum of `2` and `3`, then the second player faces the status `3, 5, 1, 4`, which has nimber `3 xor 5 xor 2 xor 3 = 7`. In order to keep it zero nimber, the second player replace the `5` by `2`, leaving the first player `3, 2, 2, 3`, which again has zero nimber.

The procedure continues, until there is no valid move for the first player.

Comment: I see how it relates to Nim, my only confusion is, the number of heaps may change in every turn. For example 0101110 initially has two heaps of size 1 and 3. If the next move is 0101**1**10 -> 0101**0**10 then now we have 3 heaps of size 1.

Comment: What you are saying is true if the piles remain the same, where as in this case the number of piles can change in every turn. How is this handled?

Comment: in the Nim algorithm, the key lemma is that if you start with a Nim sum of 0, you can't keep it zero, i.e. if you split bin a into x and y, a^x^y!=0, which translates to a!=x^y, which should always be true since x^y<=x+y (due to ^ having no carry), and x+y<a (since you have to remove at least one bit to slip a bin). that said, i think it's a really hard question if you haven't heard of Nim, especially since you have to solve it pretty much immediately during an interview.

Comment: @WhatsUp thanks for the extra explanation, sadly as Anton commented it's almost impossible to answer such question in an interview without knowing about Nim

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using graph representation.

Vertices would be the possible combinations of the given binary string/an integer with the binary -> decimal conversion.

Every vertex should have an edge connected to vertices, values of which can be obtained by making the 1 -> 0 conversion as per the game rule.

In this case, 7 bits => 2^7 = 128 combinations.
Still we can filter out the vertices that can never be reached from the given initial combination.

For example,

0101110 -> 0**0**01110 -> 0000000 (Second player wins)

0101110 -> 010**0**110 -> 0100**00**0 -> 0000000 (First player wins)

It goes on like this. In each move, we can identify the next possible combination by getting the adjacent vertices and it leads us all the way to the winning combination (0000000)

Comment: I think you're off to a good start identifying it as a graph problem, but: 1) Identifying all the possible moves from a given string is a bit tricky; it might be better to convert a string of `0`s and `1`s into a list giving the length of runs of `1`, and 2) Your graph algorithm description is woefully incomplete: suppose I have all possible paths from where I am to `000...00` - how do I use that collection of paths to determine if there's a winning strategy?